# SQL Server 2008 DBNETLIB error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Our ASp.net application is getting error as below"
[DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied "

I can connect with Enterprise manager management studio and Query analyzer without any issue.

It was running these applications with out any issue long time. last one week we are getting this error.If we restart the server .it works then it will come again after 3to 4 hours.

We are running on Windows 2003 server. I was searching and didn't find a solution yet. If anybody knows anything for this error, please post the details to resolve.

Thank you in Advance
Joseph

Comment: Re "restart the server"..which server? Database or web?

Comment: Do the access denied errors occur immediately or do they only occur after a timeout period? Is there anything in the SQL Server Error Logs relating to access being denied?

Comment: We are getting after a time period. Yesterdya evening i restrted the application server and after 5 hours i ran one dotnet application and i got message as [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (Connect()).]SQL Server does not exist or access denied . But all other application are working with out error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are running out of space on the drive that contains the tempdb.  The tempdb is purged on a restart but slowly grows as queries are executed and connections are made.  Check the drive when you start having the problem.  If you're within a few megabytes of zero, then that's the problem.  Clear-up some hard drive space, move the tempdb to another drive, or create multiple tempdb files on multiple drives.

Could also be a problem with RAM, but it's more likely to be an issue with the tempdb.